# Flutter- Accept user input from TextField after <ENTER> is pressed

Tags: flutter, input, textfield, enter, flutter-web

I'm building a browser-based app with a TextField, that should accept the user's input after  is pressed on a physical keyboard. Is this possible?
Alas, my web search didn't help much...